# Create a custom test result in pytest

Tags: pytest

I run tests that have a setup (a function-scoped fixture which yields them after the setup is done), and I want to create separation in the report between tests which failed in setup to test which failed in actual test.

Is there a way to report a custom result for a test? So the pytest report will look something like:

```
== 20 failed, 20 passed, 20 `custom_status` in 0.12s ===
```

Comment: If the fixture raises before the test could run, the test gets a special status `error` and is reported separately. Do you set a custom result besides the standard ones?

Comment: Exactly. Cause I want several distinguishable 'error' statuses.